# remove first element of a transient vector

Tags: clojure, stack

I am trying to implement the behavior of a stack in Clojure.  Taking a cue from the implementation of [`frequencies`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/841fa60b41bc74367fb16ec65d025ea5bde7a617/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L7123) I created a transient vector which I am `conj!`ing elements to (a la "push"). My issue is [`pop!`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pop!) removes elements from the end and a few other fns (`rest`,`drop`) only work on lazy sequences.

I know I could accomplish this using `loop/recur` (or `reverse`ing and `pop!`ing) but I want to better understand why removing from the beginning of a transient vector isn't allowed. I read [this](https://clojure.org/reference/transients), is it because the implementation that allows them to be mutated is only O(1) because yr only editing nodes on the end and if you changed the first node that requires copying the entire vector?

Comment: FYI Clojure's List can be used as stack.

```
(def stack '(:b :c))

(peek stack)

(pop stack)

(cons :a stack)
```

Comment: yes, it can. but as I said I was trying to emulate the behavior of `frequencies` which uses a `transient` which a list cannot be cast to and all the data structures that *can* be cast to a transient (ex. vector) implement pop as removing the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Your difficulty is not with transients: `pop` and `peek` always work at the same end of a collection as `conj` does:

- the end of a vector or
- the head of a list.

So ...

```
(= (pop (conj coll x)) coll)
```

and

```
(= (peek (conj coll x)) x)
```

... are true for any `x` for any `coll` that implements `IPersistentStack`:

- Vectors and lists do.
- Conses and ranges don't.

---

If you want to look at your stack both ways, use a vector, and use the (constant time) [`rseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rseq) to reverse it. You'd have to leave transients, though, as there is no `rseq!`. Mind you `(comp rseq`persistent!`)` is still constant time.

---

By the way, `rest` and `drop` work on any [sequence](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences), lazy or not:

```
=> (rest [1 2 3])
(2 3)
```